# What are my pages called for adding blocks?

Tags: blocks

I've searched for an answer, but cant find one. On my site I'm building I have 6 or seven main links/pages called things like Home, About us, Contacts, local issues, etc.

I want to add blocks to these pages individually, and I'm told when adding blocks that:

*"Specify pages by using their paths. Enter one path per line. The '*' character is a wildcard. Example paths are blog for the blog page and blog/* for every personal blog. (front) is the front page."*

OK, so I can use 'front' (in tags) for my home page, and that worked - but what are the other pages called? What do i put in the box other than 'front' (in tags) to get a block on say my 'Contacts' page.

I am a real newbie, and still rather overwhelmed with Drupal, so please don't asume I understand much!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have pathauto module installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you want to show your block on your 'Contact' page.
Now, have a look at your 'Contact' page URL, for example it can be `http://example.com/?q=node/2` without [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.
Now, lets create a block under that choose `Only the listed pages` then write `node/2` in the field!

[image]

Now, save block and it should work.

Comment: Thank you - I was puzzled by the node/x naming convention. I tried what you said and it worked!

Seems very odd to automatically call a page something like node/* rather than 'contacts' but fair enough, I understand how it works now at least. :-)